# Using gesture of the subclass over the gesture of the parent class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a class `MyView` subclassing `UIView` which is basically adding a tap gesture to the whole view.

I have another class `MyViewWithTextField` subclassing `MyView`. In this view, there is a `UITextField` to which I added a gesture.

My problem is that when I tap on the `UITextField`, its gesture recognizer's target is never called as it's the one from the parent's gesture recognizer that is called.

I tried to return false in `pointInside:point:withEvent` method of `MyView` when the tap is inside the `UITextField` but it doesn't change a thing.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set userInteractionEnabled on subViews, so the gesture is not ignored on the subviews.

```
subviews.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Nicely spotted! I forgot indeed I turned it off as I had a custom pad and I didn't want the system one to appear. I guess I'll look for something else than a UITextField. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`

Comment: still the same gesture recognized, the parent's one